# re-sort Polymer dom-repeat after change of value in child

Tags: javascript, sorting, polymer, dom-repeat

I have a Polymer dom-repeat list where the children get sorted o.k. on the initial value.
When I change the a value inside of the child, the depending sort order of the list is not updated. How can I best achieve that?

```
<body>
    <list-records></list-records>

    <dom-module id="list-records">
        <template>
            <template is="dom-repeat" 
                      items="{{records}}"
                      sort="sortByValue">
                <single-record record="{{item}}"
                               base="{{base}}">
                </single-record>
            </template>
        </template>
        <script>
            Polymer({
                is: 'list-records',
                properties: {
                    records: {
                        type: Array,
                        value: [
                            {number:1, value:4},
                            {number:2, value:2},
                            {number:3, value:3}]
                    }
                },
                sortByValue: function(a, b) {
                    if (a.value < b.value) return -1;
                    if (a.value > b.value) return 1;
                    return 0;
                }
            });
        </script>
    </dom-module>

    <dom-module id="single-record">
        <template>
            <div>
                Number: <span>{{record.number}}</span> 
                Value: <span>{{record.value}}</span>
                <button on-tap="_add">+</button>
            </div>
        </template>
        <script>
            Polymer({
                is: 'single-record',
                properties: {
                    record: Object,
                },
                _add: function() {
                    this.set('record.value', this.record.value + 1);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </dom-module>
</body>
```

Background: In the real location based application I have a center location (lat, lng) and get a list of keys for locations around the center. I create a child for each key. The child uses the key to get lat,lng information from a database (async). Using the lat lng information from center and from the location, I can calculate the distance inside the child. The list should be ordered by the calculated distance.

Answer (score 1):

In your `single-record` component, your `record` property does not allow two-way data binding, hence it won't change that record back to the `list-records` element. To enable two-way data binding, you must declare `record` property with `notify:true`.

```
properties: {
  record: {
    type: Object,
    notify: true
  }
}
```

Source: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the notify parameter as pointed out by [Neil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4915561/neil-john-ramal) and also 'observe' to the template (source: [How to re run dom-repeat with sort when bool property changed in Polymer element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33627446/how-to-re-run-dom-repeat-with-sort-when-bool-property-changed-in-polymer-element?rq=1)).

```
<template id="list"
          is="dom-repeat" 
          items="{{records}}"
          sort="sortByValue"
          observe="value">
```

Then it works as expected in the sample code above as well as in the real geo-location application :)

Comment: The example given above works only by setting the observe="value". I did not have to set notify. See : https://plnkr.co/edit/6MoJqj?p=preview